# Laravel : HTML::linkRoute not generate SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks, laravel-routing

**Hello My Friends.**

You can See My Title of Question
HTML::linkRoute not generate seo friendly url.
and also link_to_route not work fine.

```
{{HTML::linkRoute('test',"link to Test',array(4)}}
```

its href return

```
http://localhost/lar/public/test?4
```

but i wanna seo friendly **public/test/4**
**url** function work fine but why generator not work for me?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you probably defined your route without [parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters):

```
Route::get('/test/{id?}',array('as'=>'test', function($id){
    var_dump($id);
}));

{{HTML::linkRoute('test',"link to Test",array(4)}}
// http://localhost/lar/public/test/4
```

Comment: i write it home it is work my Home PC Win7
but not test it at Work My Work PC Ubuntu !

Comment: I Forgot use "as" in my route and its conflict with other Route

Answer (score 1):

The array is converted to a query-string. This is typically the part after the '?' in the URL. What you can do, is the following:
`{{HTML::linkRoute('test',"link to Test') . '/4/'}}`

Comment: its True i can create my link anyway possible but i have question why not works!?